# Creating a hook for common state in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a common widget that is used by several components. Each component using the common component has to have the same state variables, and I am wondering if and how this could be able to be abstracted into a custom hook. Here is the common state:

```
const [
  { leftCount, rightCount, isActive },
  setState,
] = useState({
  leftCount: 0,
  rightCount: 0,
  isActive: false,
})
```

Also some common methods:

```
const handleLeftClick = () => {
  setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    leftCount: leftCount + 1,
  }))
}
const handleRightClick = () => {
  setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    rightCount: rightCount + 1,
  }))

...
```

Comment: Have you looked into Context API?

Comment: Are you trying to share the same state between the components?  Or do they just share the same local state structure?

Comment: They just have the same state structure, and also some common methods (which I've added as examples to the original question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using react custom hooks an abstract version should be like this (You want share logic):

```
const useCommon = () => {
  const [{ leftCount, rightCount, isActive }, setState] = useState({
    leftCount: 0,
    rightCount: 0,
    isActive: false
  });

  // Rest of your logic 

  // Return everything you want (I just return a sample, You can return your handlers or anything else)
  return [{ leftCount, rightCount, isActive }, setState]; 
};
```